# How to wait for the full load of a bootstrap modal-dialog loaded with jquery .load() function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, setfocus

I have severals bootstraps modals in my website, and I load them like this :

```
function modal_density(){
    $("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/density_control.php");
    $('#all_modal').modal('show');
}
```

Then I close them like this :

```
function close_modal(){
    $("#modal-content").empty();
    $('#all_modal').modal('hide');
}
```

I want to put focus in an input of my modal, but I think that the modal is not fully loaded when I try to do that :

```
function modal_density(){
    $("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/density_control.php");
    $('#all_modal').modal('show');
    $("#element").focus();//<----Added part
}
```

How to wait for the full load of my elements ?

---

[EDIT]: I tryed this and it doesn't work :

```
function modal_controle_densite_valid(){
    $("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/controle_densite_validation.php", function() {
        $('#all_modal').modal('show');
        $("#codebarre").focus();
    });
}
```

But the following code is working after 2 sec :

```
function modal_controle_densite_valid(){
    $("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/controle_densite_validation.php", function() {
        $('#all_modal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function() {$("#codebarre").focus()}, 2000);
        //$("#codebarre").focus();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `load()` method has a second parameter which allows you to provide a function which should be executed whent he AJAX request completes. Try this:

```
function modal_density(){
    $("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/density_control.php", function() {
        $('#all_modal').modal('show').on('shown', function() {
            $("#codebarre").focus(); 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't understand. I removed the autofocus and used your function and the focus doesn't work. But i can see the modal with means that the .modal("show") is executed

Comment: No errors in the console. I add something in my post, have a look

Comment: Does the modal show with an animation, such as `fadeIn()`? It's possible the element is not available in the DOM until the animation completes.

Comment: Oh smart ! this is the modal i use : http://bootstrap2modaldemo.scripting.com/# How should I do if this is the problem ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: In that case you need to use the `shown` callback. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: Nice, it's working very well. Thanx a lot, you taught me a lot. I don't use callback as I should.

Answer (score 1):

jquery `load` takes a callback which will get executed after the loading is done

```
$("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/density_control.php",function(){
    $("#element").focus();
});
```